# Where should I declare a list of 5,000+ words?

Tags: python

I am writing a game in python in which I must periodically pull a random word from a list of words. When I prototyped my game I declared a `word_list = ['cat','dog','rat','house']` of ten words at the top of one of my modules. I then use `choice(word_list)` to get a random word. However, I must must change this temporary hack into something more elegant because I need to increase the size of the word list to 5,000+ words. If I do this in my current module it will look ridiculous.

Should I put all of these words in a flat txt file, and then read from that file as I need words? If so, how would I best do that? Put each word an a separate line and then read one random line? I'm not sure what the most efficient way is.

Comment: You haven't defined "efficient." Efficient for lookups, memory, seek time...what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put all of the words in a flat text file, one per line:

```
cat
dog
....
```

and just load it in whenever you need it with the following one-liner:

```
word_list = [word.rstrip() for word in open("words.txt","r")]
```

See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

This solution is a tad more elegant since it doesn't depend on anything but built-in functions. No importing modules required.

Be sure to cache it once it's loaded, you don't want to load the words from the file everytime you need a new word, though.

Comment: How do you close the file? I brushed up on [file objects](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and your method is mentioned as being the most elegant, however it leaves me with the question of how to close the file to "free up any system resources". When python sees a one-liner "open", which doesn't assign the object to a variable, does it inherently know to close the resulting file object? Thanks Sean!

Comment: If you use the [with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement, it will automatically clean up (close the file) when it's done: `with open("words.txt","r") as f: word_list=[word.rstrip() for word in f]` - but you are correct that my example does not properly close the file.

Answer (score 3):

Read the words from the file at startup (or at least the line indexes), and use as required.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a separated module called random_words, or something like that, hiding the list inside it and encapsulating the `choice(word_list)` inside an interface function.

As to load them from a file, well, since I would need to type them anyway, and a python file is just a text file in the end, I would type them right there, probably one per line for easy maintenance.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this idea; a word list seems like something that should be part of the data and not part of the code, and blurring the lines between those two things can often lead to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each word on a separate line in a text file, and then use `reader` (from the `csv` module) to load the file in at startup into a list. You could then randomly choose a word from the list:

```
import csv

FILENAME = 'word_list.txt'
word_list = []

# Open word list and get words
with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        word_list.append(row)
```

Even with five-thousand words you shouldn't go over fifty kilobytes of RAM, so I would consider this an efficient way to do it.

Comment: There's no need to use the `csv` module for reading such a simple file. `with open("words.txt") as f: words = [ln.strip() for ln in f]` suffices. Or maybe even `words = f.read().split()`, since 5000 words isn't particularly large.

Comment: 5,000 words isn't much.  5,000,000 isn't really that much by contemporary standards.  At 5,000,000,000, you probably should use an anydbm - the keys would be integers converted to a string, and the values would be your words.